# What does it mean to subtract '0' from a variable in C?

Tags: c, stack

```
void push(float[],float);
```

Here, `st[]` is float data-type stack and `exp[]` is char data-type array storing postfix expression.

```
  push(st,(float)(exp[i]-'0'));
```

I couldn't figure out the purpose of `(exp[i]-'0')` section though. Why are we subtracting `'0'`?

Comment: converting `char` ASCII code to `int`

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, suppose if we use "if condition" like if (isdigit(exp[i] )), then do we still need to convert  it inside the if-body??

Comment: Yes, because the value of the char is still a code, and not the value of the actual digit.

Comment: I meant to say: if(isdigit(exp[i])) { push(st,(float)(exp[i])}; is correct or still need the conversion?

Comment: I think I answered that. Yes, it still needs a conversion.

Answer (score 9):

A character is basically nothing more than an integer, whose value is the encoding of the character.

In the most common encoding scheme, [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii), the value for e.g. the character `'0'` is `48`, and the value for e.g. `'3'` is `51`. Now, if we have a variable `someChar` containing the character `'3'` and you do `someChar - '0'` it's the same as doing `51 - 48` which will result in the value `3`.

So if you have a digit read as a character from somewhere, then you subtract `'0'` to get the integer value of that digit.

This also works on other encodings, not only ASCII, because the C specification says that all encodings must have the digits in consecutive order.

Note that this "trick" is *not* guaranteed to work for any non-digit character.